# C#- I merged the Panel in the TableLayoutPanel, but it was not FULLY covered

Tags: c#

[image]

I want to merge two rows from the TableLayoutPanel.
I have used a Panel control within a TableLayoutPanel, but it is not fully merged. I would like to remove the lines that look a bit too small. I can not find a solution when I look up the reference. What should I do?

Comment: Did you set the RowSpan property of that cell?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use RowSpan and ColumnSpan properties, check below documentation for more information [check here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-span-rows-and-columns-in-a-tablelayoutpanel-control)

Comment: I proceeded like that. However, it is not completely covered.

Comment: I also set padding and margin to zero.

Comment: The `Panel` control has a `Margin` property, too.